# Does added damage from martial arts affect breakage?

Tags: house-rules, optional-rules, anima-beyond-fantasy

In a campaign I'm in an argument has come up around if it is a plausible interpretation of the rules to add breakage to attacks based on the base damage increases granted by martial arts using the "Breakage and Fortitude of natural weapons" rules in the "Creation of Beings" section (Anima - Beyond Fantasy 286):

> If you are using the optional rules for Fortitude and Breakage, you will
>   need to know what they are for the natural weapons of the beings created.
>   In this case, you can use this reference to calculate it. If a being has Increase
>   damage as a power, **increase by one point the breaking point of its weapon
>   for every +10 it has**.  (bolding mine)

So if a martial art were to grant +50 to damage, that would be a base 10 plus 40 from increases meaning a +4 to breakage.

The arguments being made are

1. The bonuses of martial arts are comparable to the Increased Damage monster power as a martial artist's unarmed strike is technically their natural weapon and that it makes sense that learning a martial art would make ones attacks better at causing Breakage
2. These are completely different bonuses and that there are already martial arts that increase Breakage so adding more on top of that is not something that is necessary

The main question here is if it would be a justifiable house rule to allow this bonus to breakage or if it is something that should be disallowed.

Comment: Long time lurker, first time poster.  Realized the lack of many Anima questions, and with all the shenanigans my group get into I figured it might be worth an outside opinion on some of them. =]

Comment: if what would be fine as a house rule? (to add breakage to attacks?)

Comment: @doppelgreener I tried to clean it up and make the question clearer, I also added more of the quote out of the book regarding the rule being utilized for this.  Hopefully this is a bit better.

Answer (score 2):

This is an acceptable ruling, in that it does not insurmountably disrupt the ki subsystem.  Consider, however, the 'breakage augmentation' and 'fortitude augmentation' powers on page 103 of the rule book.  These powers allow ki users to alter the effects of their weapons in terms of breakage and fortitude. +5 breakage costs but 2 ki as a secondary power and requires but 5 Martial Knowledge.  50 damage bonus costs almost three times as much! This helps us see that including a +1/10 bonus to breakage for free does not eliminate the value of breakage boosting secondary effects on a ki technique, even if it does diminish it.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I remember the only way to add Breakage as a Martial Artist, is to develop a Ki technique. I think some Martial Arts also add at advanced and master a breakage bonus but that is all.

I'll need to check in the Dominus Exxet for additionnal info.

Answer (score -2):

Natural weapons and unarmed combat are two different things. Natural weapons are claws, horns, spikes, teeth... that said creature has. Humans in Anima do not have natural weapons and when they fight with martial arts (exceptions aside) they use unarmed combat rules.

I do not remember where I read the breakage of unarmed combat, but I think I it is -2. Of course Ki abilities and some martial arts give bonus to this (and of course, having a lot of strength).

Finally, using this rule will be unfair, since most of martial arts give different numbers for base damage, not 10.

I will have to check, but I do remember that, even more, you cannot combine natural weapons with martial arts.

Comment: Do you happen to know where you are finding the -2 base breakage of unarmed combat?  I'm looking through this now and while I can find bonuses from Strength I can't find the actual base listed anywhere.